# Error when statically linking libgmp on Linux

Tags: c, static-linking, gmp

The GMP docs say that static linking may provide a small performance improvement.

I am having a problem getting it to staticly link libgmp on my Linux systems.  I've narrowed down the issue I'm having to a tiny test case.

gmptest.c

```
#include <gmp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    mpz_t foo;
    mpz_init(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all: clean gmptest static

clean:
    rm -f *.s
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f gmptest
    rm -f static-gmptest

gmptest: Makefile gmptest.c
    gcc -std=c99 -O3 -lgmp gmptest.c -o gmptest

static: clean Makefile gmptest.c
    gcc -std=c99 -O3 -static /usr/lib/libgmp.a gmptest.c -o static-gmptest
```

The non-static binary is compiled and linked without any issues, but 'Make static' produces:

```
gcc -std=c99 -O3 -static /usr/lib/libgmp.a gmptest.c -o static-gmptest
/tmp/ccWSFke9.o: In function `main':
gmptest.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `__gmpz_init'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [static] Error 1
```

The library does exist:

```
chris@vostro:~/Dropbox/static$ ls -lA /usr/lib/libgmp.a 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1041666 2010-02-26 13:20 /usr/lib/libgmp.a
```

I have also tried -lgmp for the static linking, but the error is the same.

This is all on Ubuntu 10.04 and 10.10 AMD64.

Can some enlighten me as to the obvious error I'm making?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: Have you tried reordering so that libraries-needed is *after* users-of-library on the command line?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
 gcc -std=c99 -O3 -static gmptest.c -lgmp -o static-gmptest
```

since libraries should always be linked in the good order, and after the program or object files using them.

Comment: Thanks, it was the order of linking.

Comment: This happens quite often to people new to C/C++. I wonder whether they will add some sort of warning in the future. It would certainly save a lot of time.

Comment: Now, this is fine, if you want to have everything linked statically

Answer (score 0):

Here, in GMP 6.1.2 / MINGW and assuming certain portability, I find that the header "gmp.h" has fix link mode, as configured with GMP build parameters.

```
/* Instantiated by configure. */
#if ! defined (__GMP_WITHIN_CONFIGURE)
    #define _LONG_LONG_LIMB 1
    #define __GMP_LIBGMP_DLL  0
#endif
```

As with this the compiler will never generate static object decorations, and so the linker will never match the static libgmp, I conditioned the define `__GMP_LIBGMP_DLL`

```
/* Added link switch GMP_STATIC */
#if ! defined (__GMP_WITHIN_CONFIGURE)
    #define _LONG_LONG_LIMB 1
    #ifndef GMP_STATIC // SGR 2021-12-30
        #define __GMP_LIBGMP_DLL  1
    #endif
#endif
```

Now, with defined `GMP_STATIC` the static `libgmp.a` is successfully attracted and without `GMP_STATIC` the dynamic `libgmp.dll.a`.